# Quiz form with JavaScript

Tags: arrays, object

I'm new here? and i am learning Javascript. Today i have faced some problems, and i hope you will help me to solve it.

I'm trying to make a quiz with no html, javascript only. Questions and answer i want to import from questions database, which has a form of array iwth objects.

So i made heading and questions. And the problem is, how to make each question to have it's own variants of answers. Here is my code `

```
var QBase=[];

// Question 1
var q = {
    q:"Question 1",
    a:[
    "Answer 11",
    "Answer 12"
    ]
}
QBase.push(q);

// Question 2
var q = {
    q:"Question 2",
    a:[
    "Answer 21",
    "Answer 22",
    "Answer 23",
    "Answer 24",
    "Answer 25"
    ]
}

QBase.push(q);

// Question 3
var q = {
    q:"Question 3",
    a:[
    "Answer 31",
    "Answer 32",
    "Answer 33"
    ]
}
QBase.push(q);
```

var qForm={

```
ancestor:document.body,
wrapper:'',
header:'',
questionBlock:'',
question:[],
answerBlock:[],
answer:[],


createForm:function(){
    this.wrapper=document.createElement('form');
    this.wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');
    this.ancestor.appendChild(this.wrapper);
},
createHeader:function(){
    this.header=document.createElement('h1');
    this.wrapper.classList.add('header');
    this.header.innerHTML='LALALALAAL';
    this.wrapper.appendChild(this.header);
},
createQuestionBlock:function(){
    this.questionBlock=document.createElement('ol');
    this.questionBlock.classList.add('questionBlock');
    this.wrapper.appendChild(this.questionBlock);
},
createQuestion:function(i){
    this.question[i]=document.createElement('li');
    this.question[i].classList.add('question'+i);   
    this.question[i].innerHTML=QBase[i].q;
    this.questionBlock.appendChild(this.question[i]);


},
createAnswerBlock:function(i){
    this.answerBlock[i]=document.createElement('ol');
    this.answerBlock[i].classList.add('AnswerBlock');
    this.question[i].appendChild(this.answerBlock[i]);
},
createAnswer:function(i){
    this.answer[i]=document.createElement('li');
    this.answer[i].classList.add('answer'+i);
    this.answer[i].innerHTML=QBase[i].a;
    this.answerBlock[i].appendChild(this.answer[i]);

},

createTest:function(){
    this.createForm();
    this.createHeader();
    this.createQuestionBlock();
    for (var i=0; i<QBase.length; i++){
        this.createQuestion(i);
    }
    for (var i=0;i<QBase.length;i++){
        this.createAnswerBlock(i);
    }
    for (var i=0;i<QBase.length;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<QBase[i].a.length;j++){
            this.createAnswer(a[i],q[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

}
qForm.createTest();
`
output looks like this[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6t3m.png)

but i need something like this [desirable output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1xyz.png)

Comment: Are you unsure if you are new?

Answer (score 0):

Try to nest your answers in your for loops

Something like:

```
  for (var i=0; i<QBase.length; i++){
    this.createQuestion(i);

    for (var i=0;i<QBase.length;i++){
        this.createAnswerBlock(i);

        for (var i=0;i<QBase.length;i++){
            for(var j=0;j<QBase[i].a.length;j++){
                this.createAnswer(a[i],q[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you create the html with javascript in the first place?